# Should PS1 be defined before exported in .bash_profile?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, macos

In .bash_profile, should PS1 be defined before exporting?

As an example, the first line in my .bash_profile is currently:

`export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "`

But instead, should it be:

```
PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export PS1
```

Answer (score 4):

In korn shell and bash, you can do it in one line. The original bourne shell required your second syntax, where you set it on one line and then exported it.